# No System Images available in Android SDK manager to enable AVD creation

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I've just upgraded the Android Support libraries and thus the minimum version of the OS required for me Xamarin Forms app and now want to test it on some devices. I can run it on my phone just fine but wanted to create an Android 7.1.1 (API 25) or Android 8.0.0 (API 26) emulator to test on. 
However when I go to create a new AVD, I get the message

> No System Images installed for this target

So I flip over in to the SDK manager, but there are no system images available:

[image]

So my question is, where and how do I get these system images? Or am I just not able to create AVD's for these API versions for some reason?

I've tried adding new sources, including this one:

> https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img2-1.xml

But it hasn't made any difference. Do I need different sources for later API versions?

Comment: I think that you are using an obsolete SDK Manager. Where is the screenshot from?

Comment: You need to create them (and download the images) passing through Android Studio, SDK Manager is deprecated.

Comment: I'm just using the button on the toolbar in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

Comment: I think the button is not working anymore, have you read [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92430/standalone-sdk-manager-and-avd-manager-are-deprecated-since-android-studio-2-3)?

Comment: Yeah, the button opens the same SDK manager and AVD manager linked to in that post, located (in my case) at: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe"

Comment: The new SDK images available will only be published inside the new AVD Manager of Android Studio. You should try to download them from there before and then launch them from VS

Answer (score 0):

> No System Images installed for this target

Check your SDK Update sites, make sure that it contains these entries:

```
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/android/sys-img.xml
https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sys-img.xml
```

[image]
[image]

Then, start SDK Manager as Administrator again, download the API 25 and API 26 system image if they are listed.

[image]

After download the system image, you could create an Android 7.1.1 (API 25) or Android 8.0.0 (API 26) emulator.